Creation mountain to space? (theoretical)
I think 100 kilometers height is enough to make an some kind of space-mountain base-factory there and it seems to be cheeper to transport resourses there then to usual space stations.
I am interesting in several questions:

It is obvious that handmade mountain with this size will have a huge weight, so it may press too much, and it may create some crack in earth with lava. Is anything like that possible?
What about ozone layer it is lower than 100 kilometers, so it may case some problems on the earth, am I right?
Will this mountain cause some kind of gravitational problems, like a satellite falling off or something like that?
What other problems might this cause after the fact (of its existing)?
Is it theoretical possible to make this mountain and the base? Like anought materials on earth, proper place on earth to do it, any theoretical building tactic to build it faster, is humanity has enough technology to make some protection from space on the mountain like meteors, lack of air, ozone, radiation, gravitation, temperature, etc?
Is it possible for the material to shrink due to weight during construction to create empty spaces that could cause problems or something like that?


100km is too high for a mountain on a terran planet.
Mountains and mountain ranges are (nearly) in isostatic equilibrium (Isostasy) to not sink into the crust. It works with mountains and mountain ranges a bit like with ice cubes in a glass of water or maybe more like pieces of fruit placed on a yoghurt: only a certain part can extrude from the surface, and it will sink-in if too much weight is placed on a certain area.
The Himalayan on Earth are about as high as mountains can get on Earth - they are barely supported by their mountain roots in the mantle. Making it higher would mean they sink further into the mantle to a point where the root would dissolve in the overall mantle.
The highest mountain in the Solar System is Olympus Mons on Mars with a bit more than 20km height - as Mars' gravity is only 40% of that of Earth, it can support much higher mountains with the same strength of the mantle material.
